# reshaping and re-arranging array using octave / matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave, reshape

I'm trying to reshape an array, perform an operation and then reshape it back to the original.  See example of the output I'm trying to get.  I can get `a` and `b` but I'm having trouble getting `c` to look like `a` again.

Step 1) (the original array)

```
    1                     1                     1
    2                     2                     2
    3                     3                     3
    4                     4                     4
    5                     5                     5
```

Step 2) (reshape and perform some operation)

```
1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5
```

Step 3) (array is reshaped back to the original size to look like `step 1`) **this is what I want**

```
    1                     1                     1
    2                     2                     2
    3                     3                     3
    4                     4                     4
    5                     5                     5
```

I can get the variables `a` and `b` but I'm not sure how to reshape `c` from `b` to look like `a` again see example code and output below

```
a=[repmat(1,[1,3]);repmat(2,[1,3]);repmat(3,[1,3]);repmat(4,[1,3]);repmat(5,[1,3])]
[rw,col]=size(a)
b=reshape(a',1,rw*col)
c=reshape(b,rw,col)

a=
        1                     1                     1
        2                     2                     2
        3                     3                     3
        4                     4                     4
        5                     5                     5

b=1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5


c =

                     1                     2                     4
                     1                     3                     4
                     1                     3                     5
                     2                     3                     5
                     2                     4                     5
```

Ps: I'm using Octave 4.0 which is like Matlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MATLAB and Octave use column-major ordering so you'll need to reshape the result with that in mind. The data will be filled *down the columns first* but you want it to fill the *columns first*. To achieve this, you can specify the number of columns as the number of rows provided to `reshape` and then transpose the result

```
c = reshape(b, 3, []).'
```

Or more flexibly

```
c = reshape(b, flip(size(a))).'
```